# Rescource: Sketch File 4.0 (Symbols Document) isn't available in English?

Tags: antd

When downloading the Sketch Resource on https://ant.design/docs/resources > RENEW Sketch Symbols, everything inside the document is Japanese (?) instead of English. Where can I find the english resource? (And yes I am browsing the site in english). When downloading the XD version it is English. My company however does everything in Sketch wand would prefer that format!

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Found out that Sketch files are just Chinese open source and not translated. Paid versions are. Just putting it out there.